# Why is 1 not a critical point for this function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x-1}$, why is $1$ not a critical point, along with $0$ and $2$? Don't critical points include discontinuities?

Comment: Critical points must be in the domain of the function.

Comment: @user252075 Do you know what is going on at $x=1$ ? Did you graph the function? That might help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of the function is {$x \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq 1$}, and thus as $x=1$ is not in the domain of $f(x)$ it cannot be a critical point.

Logically, if a point is not in the domain of a function $f$, it does not exist for $f$, and thus it cannot be a critical point for $f$.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia: In mathematics, a critical point or stationary point of a differentiable function of a real or complex variable is any value in its domain where its derivative is 0 or undefined.

The thing is that $x=1$ could only be a critical point of $f(x)$ if $f(x)$ was differentiable at $x=1$. However, since differentiable $\Rightarrow$ continous, if $f(x)$ is not continous at $x=1$ nor it can be differentiable at $x=1$, meaning that $x=1$ cannot be a critical point, because the derivative doesn't exist there.